# String does not name a type

Tags: c++

I am using Net beans to create a banking application
I have three files
Client.h, Client.CPP and main.CPP

```
//Client.h
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H
using namespace std;
class Client {
public:
    Client();
    Client(const Client& orig);
    virtual ~Client();
private:
    string fname;
    string lname;

};

#endif /* CLIENT_H */

//Client.cpp
#include "Client.h"

Client::Client() {
}

Client::Client(const Client& orig) {
}

Client::~Client() {
}
```

When i compile my project i get the following error
String does not name a type although i am using namespace std;

Comment: You are missing `#include <string>`

Comment: Don't put `using namespace std;` in a header file. If the person who includes the header file wants to pollute their namespace, that is their prerogative, but you shouldn't force the pollution on them.

Answer (score 1):

`#include <string>` is needed.

std namespace is one thing, but in order to let the compile known the string name,
you should tell it.

Comment: Where should i put it?